# Image hover is centred and not relative to link that is being hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, containers

On a website I'm working on I got images inside a container that need to appear over the text on hover. This works smooth BUT..

Whenever an image appears it stays in the same location as the previous hover. I am trying to make the images only appear over the link it is associated with but it won't work.

I have some JavaScript running to randomize the link colors.

You can find the webpage in action over here:http://bravenewfashion.com/menu.html Its on the tab titled 'Biology meets Fashion'

Comment: Can you show some code to show us what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Olly, could you show us your code ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GzAYubPxv7tVjMiJwE2BnHAnjA4gtyPr?usp=sharing

Comment: @nsayer thanks for the response. I have no idea how to put it on here so I have uploaded some screenshots to google drive

Comment: @OllyLenain I don't see any css or js code where you position the image? You should either nest your images in your html right beside (or inside) each link, or calculate the `top` and `left` values for the image on hover. If you can create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or other example I can help more.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda thank you for the advice. is this ok? https://jsfiddle.net/ollylenain/z6hew58u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the working example. If you nest the image **inside** of the `a` tag, it will automatically position itself next to the link. You can then add some rules for `top` and `left` to position them over the link like your website does now.

[**Working JSFiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/z6hew58u/3/)

Comment: amazing thank you! I really appreciate the help. Is it possible to stop the text that is behind from moving down when the image is open?

Comment: @OllyLenain Yes, you can add `position: relative` to the `.imgTrigger` class and then change the `.hoverImage` to `position: absolute`: https://jsfiddle.net/z6hew58u/7/